# How to fix .htaccess corrupted

Tags: htaccess

I was working on the live site, I think the plugin cause file .htaccess corrupted so my site is down "500 Internal Server Error", I read a solution to rename .htaccess but when I use Filezilla to do it get "550 rename failed" so I can not rename it, I try to go setting -> save permalinks but not working. is there anyway other way to fix .htaccess error? please help me its emergency.

Comment: You could try just deleting the .htaccess and then re-saving the permalinks to regenerate a completely new .htaccess file. Also, what plugin did you install before this happened?

Comment: Custom permalinks - oh my god, it works very great at first but then it actually has something to do with woocommerce - WMPL cause my whole site went down. thanks for your help but it not .htaccess can fix it but I try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reverting back to the default `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If you're using some other "flavor" of WP (e.g. multisite) view the [htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) docs on the Codex for the appropriate `.htaccess` setup.